# Bash way to update ServerLimit in httpd.conf

Tags: bash, sed, httpd.conf

I have to update the value of ServerLimit ... since this is not at the beginning of the line, the vale is not getting changed.

```
<IfModule mpm_event_module>
    StartServers                           20
    ServerLimit 125
    Mutex fcntl:${ORACLE_INSTANCE}/servers/${COMPONENT_NAME}/logs
</IfModule>
```

I have used this :

```
sed -i "s|\("^ServerLimit" * *\).*|\1170|" httpd.conf
```

This works when the string to search is at the beginning of the line as below:

```
<IfModule mpm_event_module>
    StartServers                           20
ServerLimit 125
    Mutex fcntl:${ORACLE_INSTANCE}/servers/${COMPONENT_NAME}/logs
</IfModule>
```

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: `sed -E -i 's/ServerLimit.*/ServerLimit 1170/' file`?

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
sed -Ei 's|(ServerLimit) [0-9]+|\1 170|' httpd.conf
```

Comment: This might possibly match "ServerLimit" in some other context; how about `...s|^([[:space:]]*ServerLimit)[[:space:]]+[0-9]+$| ...`?

Comment: Choosing a regexp metachar (`|`) as the delimiter for a script that uses regexps obfuscates your code at best. Just pick some other char that's not a metachar, e.g. the traditional `/`, or `:` or `#` or `,` or `@` if you feel a burning desire to change it. Consider/try `echo 'abc' | sed -E 's|a|c|d|'` for example.